# Ancient greek translation exercise - narration, meaning of singular *οὔτε*

Tags: greek, translation-check, greek-to-english-translation

In *First Greek Book* by John Williams White following passage is given for reader to translate:

> Τισσαφέρνες δέ, ὀ τῆς Καρίας σατράπης, τῷ Κύρῳ πολέμιος ἦν, τότε δὲ οὔτε ἐστράτευεν ἐπ' αὔτε διήρπαζε τὴν χώραν.

I am pretty convinced that:

> Τισσαφέρνες δέ, ὀ τῆς Καρίας σατράπης, τῷ Κύρῳ πολέμιος ἦν,

means something like
*Tissarphernes, satrap of Caria, was warlike to the Cyrus*

and

> αὔτε διήρπαζε τὴν χώραν

says something like:
*he had plundered the country again*

This leaves me with:

> τότε δὲ οὔτε ἐστράτευεν ἐπ'

*τότε δὲ* - and then

*ἐστράτευεν* - he advanced with army

*ἐπ'* is without a noun and maybe means here: apart from [the fact that he plundered the country]

*οὔτε* can be used as *οὔτε ... οὔτε* - neither ... nor but here it's different. It's unclear for me - if Tissarphernes was enemy of Cyrus and he plundered the country then he most likely **did** advance with army - what could *οὔτε* mean here, then?

If I ignore *οὔτε* attempt at translation would then be:

> Tissarpernes, satrap of Caria, was warlike to the Cyrus and then he had advanced with army apart from plundering the country again.

Could you please help me and correct errors?

Comment: There seems to something wrong with what you've given: *ep'* should have a noun/pronoun after it, in the accusative, to complete the idea of *estrateuen*. Are you sure you copied correctly and that there shouldn't be an *auton* after *ep'* and then a repetition of *oute*? I think *tote de* in this instance is adversative: Tissaphernes was (in general) hostile to Cyrus, but on the occasion in question, he neither advanced his army against him nor ravaged the country. (Sorry for the transliterated Greek. It's just a pain to type in Greek on my Windows PC.)

Comment: That correction can be confirmed here:  http://cdn.textkit.net/JWW_First_Greek_Book.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it appears that you transcribed the passage incorrectly. Here is the corrected text:

> Τισσαφέρνης δέ, ὁ τῆς Καρίας σατράπης, τῷ Κύρῳ πολέμιος ἦν, τότε δὲ οὔτε ἐστράτευεν ἐπ᾿ **αὐτὸν οὔτε** διήρπαζε τὴν χώραν.

Here you have a correlation of οὔτε...οὔτε ("neither...nor"), and most of your difficulties should disappear. Here is a translation:

> But Tissaphernes, the satrap of Caria, was Cyrus's enemy (lit: "hostile to Cyrus"), but at that time he neither waged war against him [i.e. Cyrus] nor plundered the country.

Comment: Thank you!
It's quite embarassing - I copied it incorrectly into my notes, was unable to translate it and then copied from my notes into the question.